# how to identify enter character in input?

Tags: jquery, css, unicode

I want to identify enter character in one input text and action one work.but I'm new in jquery and css.

I want when enter certain word in input text can identify Unicode this word (for example if this word was Arabic direction this input to be 'rtl' and if this word was English direction to be 'ltr' also if this enter word was numbers direction to be 'ltr')

I don't know about it. please tell me about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or u can try this

```
$('.inputtext').keyup( function () {
  var inputtext= $(this).val();
});
```

or

```
$('#inputtext').keyup( function () {
      var inputtext= $(this).val();
    });
```

Comment: @janatan can u post ur html code then it woud be better to understand the problem

Comment: my friend how to get first value from enter word?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get the value entered in the input text box on keyup.

Note : input text box calss should be  **class="inputtext"**

```
$('.inputtext').live("keyup", function () {
  var inputtext= $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"Enter" results in a carriage return character, a line feed character, or both. In most languages, carriage return, or newline, is represented as '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.keyup` event

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {

      if(e.keyCode === 13) {
           // 13 corresponds to enter key

          // your code here when user presses enter key
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These properties are described by Unicode. While most browsers should contain this data on their own somewhere, it is not accessible from JavaScript. To use this data, then, you'll have to go to the source: [`UnicodeData.txt`](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt). In particular, the “bidirectional class values” are in the fourth (zero-indexed) field of that file. For more information about the format of the file, see [Unicode Standard Annex #44](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/), and in particular, [the description of the possible bidirectional class values](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Bidi_Class_Values).

Generally, what you'll want to do is extract the code point from the string using [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). This will return an integer. You will want to find the corresponding bidirectional class for the character with that code point (zeroth column).

This should work for every character in the Basic Multilingual Plane. For characters outside of the BMP, you'll have to decode the UTF-16 surrogates. Information on how to do this is available elsewhere.